# Relative image files not found. Background render. No error, just magenta textures

Tags: image, command-line, path

Another one of these problems...

Renders fine on Windows desktop, but not on headless Linux box.  Image files are in the same dir as the blend file, like on the desktop.  Using relative paths.  CLI output shows it's loading image files, but gives no error as it probably should since the I get the magenta textures.

Using identical blender versions btw desktop and Linux, v2.76.

Using --debug-all is no help.

Command:
`blender -b --debug-all -noaudio internet3.blend -s 1069 -e 1069 -a`

Any suggestions?

Edit: The strange thing is, a referenced movie file IS successfully found and included in the render even though the images are not.

Comment: pack your textures on the file... **magenta textures means missing textures**, they are probably linked to a path on your windows desktop that is not accesible (or is named differently) for your linux box.

Comment: @cegaton that makes no sense.  It's using relative paths, supposedly, which evaluates to the current dir of the blend file.  That shouldn't cause a problem between platforms.  I cannot pack the images since they total 2 GB which would make uploading the blend to the cloud for rendering a real PITA.  And I know magenta means missing textures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  The clue was that another asset, a movie, *was* found and rendered, but it was in a subdir instead of being the the same dir as the blend file.  So, I moved the images from the same dir as the blend file to their own images subdir.  Then, open the blend file and select File > External Data > Make all files relative.  Save.